debian 12 image error on GCP
The documentation says debian 12 is supported
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/os-details
but I'm getting this error when I try to import an image:

[import-image]: 2024-04-22T14:18:01Z os debian-12 is invalid.
Allowed values: [centos-7 centos-stream-8 centos-stream-9 debian-10
debian-11 debian-8 debian-9 opensuse-15 rhel-6 rhel-6-byol rhel-7
rhel-7-byol rhel-8 rhel-8-byol rhel-9 rhel-9-byol rocky-8 rocky-9
sles-12 sles-12-byol sles-15 sles-15-byol sles-sap-12 sles-sap-12-byol
sles-sap-15 sles-sap-15-byol ubuntu-1404 ubuntu-1604 ubuntu-1804
ubuntu-2004 ubuntu-2204 windows-10-x64-byol windows-10-x86-byol
windows-2008r2 windows-2008r2-byol windows-2012 windows-2012-byol
windows-2012r2 windows-2012r2-byol windows-2016 windows-2016-byol
windows-2019 windows-2019-byol windows-2022 windows-2022-byol
windows-7-x64-byol windows-7-x86-byol windows-8-x64-byol
windows-8-x86-byol]


It turns out GCP are changing their image import functionality and it has been moved to Migrate to Virtual Machines which is currently in preview. Here debian-12 is supported:

Official Google response here

Checking on the documentation, there was no indication that Debian 12 was included for importing an image.

Even on this documentation, import for Debian 12 shows that it is not supported
